# SQL Conversion to Linq conversion for .NET Core

Tags: linq, .net-core

Here is my SQL query. I'm trying to produce the same results in my .NET Core web app using a linq query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.BUD
WHERE LEFT(PeriodD, 4) = YEAR(GETDATE())
```

Here is what I've tried with no success in my linq query

```
List<SelectListItem> budNames = _ctx.Budgets.AsNoTracking()     
            .Where(n => (n.Period, 4) == GETDATE())  
            .Select(n => new SelectListItem
                             {
                                 // values
                             }).ToList();
```

Comment: Is n.Period of type DateTime?

Comment: Its a character fields YYYYMM, sorry that probably would have been helpful.

Comment: The comparison **must** be all means include `YEAR(GETDATE())` - otherwise, you're comparing to one specific moment in time - not a whole yeaR!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mainly this line causes you problems:

```
.Where(n=> (n.Period,4) == GetDate())
```

To get the first 4 characters of a string, use the [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0) method:

```cs
n.Period.Substring(0, 4) // beginn 0 away from the first char, take 4 of them
```

To get a sting of the current year ([DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-5.0)):

```
var currentYear = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");
```

Applied to your example:

```cs
var currentYear = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");
List<SelectListItem> budNames = _ctx.Budgets.AsNoTracking()     
    .Where(n => n.Period.Substring(0, 4) == currentYear)  
    .Select(n => new SelectListItem
    {
        // values
    }).ToList();
```

Or, you could use the StartsWith method:

```cs
var currentYear = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");
List<SelectListItem> budNames = _ctx.Budgets.AsNoTracking()     
    .Where(n => n.Period.StartsWith(currentYear))  
    .Select(n => new SelectListItem
    {
        // values
    }).ToList();
```